# Google Analytics with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up the new google analytics tag for my angularjs website.

I basically added this to my `index.html`:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GOOGLE-ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GOOGLE-ID'); //remove in order to avoid sending hits on index twice
</script>
```

This is my script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['plangular','ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'slick', 'chart.js', 'ngMeta']);
```

I added:

```
app.run(['ngMeta', '$rootScope' , '$location', '$window', function(ngMeta,$rootScope , $location, $window) { 
  ngMeta.init();


        $window.gtag('create', 'GOOGLE-ID', 'auto');


        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event) {
            $window.gtag('send', 'pageview', $location.path());
        });

}]);
```

But I'm not able to see any hits on the analytics page, except for the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics. It works well and has detailed installation instructions. You can even send events to multiple analytic services.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the gtag was not working but I switched to the old Google Analytics snippet and it's now working perfectly. I followed this doc: https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-google-analytics/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GOOGLE-ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GOOGLE-ID', { 'send_page_view': false });
</script>
```

This will ensure that index doesn't count as a pageview when it loads. Then in your `$stateChangeSuccess`:

```
app.run(['ngMeta', '$rootScope', '$location', '$window', function(ngMeta, $rootScope , $location, $window) { 
  ngMeta.init();

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event) {
      $window.gtag('config', 'GOOGLE-ID', {'page_path': $location.path()});
      $window.gtag('event', 'page_view');
  });

}]);
```

Your code should now be firing pageviews for each state change. Gtag doesn't have `create` or `send` handlers. I think it only supports `js`, `config`, `set`, and `event` as the first param.

See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications for more info about using Gtag in SPAs.

Comment: This is not working, no routes are sent to analytics

Comment: Sorry! Edited answer to add 'page_view' event.

Comment: The 'event, 'page_view' is just a custom event, it's the line above that that sends the actual page view. Just a note for anyone looking at this

Answer (score -1):

I suggest embedding the [Segment script](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-angular#%EF%B8%8F-step-1-copy-the-snippet) into your `index.html`, extend analytics library onto the `window` object, and add tracking calls onto the `(click)` event handler:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup-btn',
  template: `
    <button (click)="trackEvent()">
      Signup with Segment today!
    </button>
  `
})
export class SignupButtonComponent {
  trackEvent() {
    window.analytics.track('User Signup');
  }
}
```

I’m the maintainer of https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-angular. I recommend checking it out if you want to solve this problem by using one singular API to manage your customer data, and be able to integrate into any other analytics tool (we support over 250+ destinations) - without writing any additional code.

Comment: the question was about AngularJS, not Angular (2+)